# cross compiling latest qt for existing raspberry pi setup from windows

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am running a windows 10 host machine which is connected to a raspberry pi over SSH. What I would like to do is cross compile the latest qt 5.9 on my windows machine for the raspberry pi.

All the stuff I found online instruct to put a new linux image on my raspberry pi but I do not want to change the existing configuration. Is it possible to create an image from the existing pi module and build qt for that installation (on the windows machine).

As far as I understand it, I need to somehow create the PI environment on the windows machine and then I can ask Qt to build itself against this image and the compilation tools in it and then I can copy the Qt binaries over. Is that correct? Sorry it is my first time trying to do something like this.

Comment: I prefer to work on the Pi directly. You can create samba share so that you can access source files on Pi, but build the project *on* the Pi via SSH console. This way you will not face any incompatibility issues and struggling with your environment, which might be pain in the ass.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs My issue is that the PI is on a custom board and I can only connect via ssh over Ethernet. So, if I build qt on it, I'm afraid it will not have enough disk space to do it properly.

Comment: I have USB SSD connected to Pi for the root filesystem, and also only SSH access over Ethernet, no display. This makes Pi a remote development machine, rather than a plain target. Recommend you to do the same - very convenient.